# Sequential File upload in angular

Tags: angular

How to upload file Sequentially in angular.
I want to upload file after successful upload of first and then so on.
if we use http post its asynchronous so it is not waiting for first one to complete.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/FileUploads/fileupload', formData, options)
.subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log("Subscribe data", data);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message, JSON.parse(err.error).error.message);
    }
)

}
```

Comment: How about if you store all files inside an array and then loop through the array and send one by one to the upload method? Its a generic answer because no extra information is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mergeMap for this, stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-observable-example-gjb4kh?file=index.js) :

```
import { Observable, mergeMap } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';


//random facts about cat with each call
let url = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact';
    
// returns an observable of the http request
//replace this in your code with your post call like: this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/FileUploads/fileupload', formData, options);
const httpRequestObservable = ajax.get(url);

httpRequestObservable
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((x) => {
      console.log(1);
      console.log(Date.now());
      console.log(x.response.fact);
      console.log(Date.now());
      return httpRequestObservable;
    }),
    mergeMap((y) => {
      console.log(2);
      console.log(Date.now());
      console.log(y.response.fact);
      console.log(Date.now());
      return httpRequestObservable;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((z) => {
    console.log(3);
    console.log(Date.now());
    console.log(z.response.fact);
    console.log(Date.now());
    console.log('result');
  });
```